# Is there any option to import specific databases from all databases dump

Tags: mysql, dump

Is there any option to import only required databases from a all database back up .

Comment: Hope it is mysqldump backup..you can restore invoking mysql client with -o --one-database <dbname> and then providing your file..see mysql --help says " -o, --one-database  Ignore statements except those that occur while the
                     default database is the one named at the command line."..hope it helps

Comment: If you have sed handy, using it may be a bit faster: http://www.darrenmothersele.com/blog/2012/01/10/restore-single-db-from-complete-mysql-dump.html